# ¿Como apuntar dominios a subdominios externos?

Tags: redirección, dominio, subdominio

Buenas y gracias de antemano por vuestro tiempo.

Mi necesidad es que necesito que usen una aplicación web varios clientes pero no quiero que tengan acceso a código fuente, y me gustaría que cada cliente pueda acceder a la aplicación desde su dominio personal.

- He pensado si es posible apuntar un dominio (dominio cliente) a un subdominio de un dominio mío (cada subdominio podría tener una aplicación personalizada).

Ej:

```
www.dominio1.com -> Apunte a subdominio1.dominiopersonal.com
www.dominio2.com -> Apunte a subdominio2.dominiopersonal.com
www.dominio3.com -> Apunte a subdominio3.dominiopersonal.com
...
```

y cada subdominio tiene una aplicación web diferente.
¿Se puede?

- Otra posibilidad sería colocarle in iframe en su index.html, pero no me parece una solución profesional, nunca me ha gustado mucho la idea del iframe.

¿o.. hay otra posibilidad de hacer esto?

Comment: Si se puede, porque es así como funciona. Cuando compras un dominio tenes que configurar los NS. Luego en tu servidor das de alta la cuenta y el dominio (_basicamente es para que el servidor sepa donde estan los archivos_) y listo.

Comment: Creo que no me has entendido, quiero que cada dominio de cada cliente apunte a un subdominio diferente de un dominio alojado en mi servidor.

Comment: Pero vos queres que el cliente siga viendo su dominio, cierto? ¿que panel usas para administrar tu hosting?

Comment: Plesk y serían varios clientes cada uno con una web diferente, fíjate en el ejemplo que puse en la descripción.

Comment: ¿Vos queres hacer una redirección o que el dominio resuelva en otro lado? No entiendo porque queres crear sub-dominios. Aunque podes hacer que ambos dominios resuelvan en el mismo lugar y directorio

Comment: Mira el ejemplo que puse, justo es lo que quiero. Quiero que cada cliente pueda ver su web a través de su dominio y que cada web esté alojada en un subdominio de mi dominio. ¿Es posible?